# Sorting the catalog results by multiple fields

Tags: python, plone

I need to sort the catalog results by multiple fields.

In my case, first sort by year, then by month. The year and month field are included in my custom content type (`item_publication_year` and `item_publication_month` respectively).

However, I'm not getting the results that I want. The year and month are not ordered at all. They should appear in descending order i.e. 2006, 2005, 2004 etc.

Below is my code:

```
def queryItemRepository(self):
    """
    Perform a search returning items matching the criteria
    """

    query = {}

    portal_catalog = getToolByName(self, 'portal_catalog')
    folder_path = '/'.join( self.context.getPhysicalPath() )

    query['portal_type'] = "MyContentType"
    query['path'] = {'query' : folder_path, 'depth' : 2 }

    results = portal_catalog.searchResults(query)

    # convert the results to a python list so we can use the sort function
    results = list(results)  

    results.sort(lambda x, y : cmp((y['item_publication_year'], y['item_publication_year']), 
                                   (x['item_publication_month'], x['item_publication_month'])
                                  ))


    return results
```

Anyone care to help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better bet is to use the `key` parameter for sorting:

```
results.sort(key=lambda b: (b.item_publication_year, b.item_publication_month))
```

You can also use the [`sorted()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) instead of using `list()`; it'll return a sorted list for you, it's the same amount of work for Python to first call `list` on the results, then sort, as it is to just call `sorted`:

```
results = portal_catalog.searchResults(query)
results = sorted(results, key=lambda b: (b.item_publication_year, b.item_publication_month))
```

Naturally, both `item_publication_year` and `item_publication_month` need to be present in the catalog metadata.

Comment: You are a genius. I used the second option and added `reverse=True`. It worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can get multiple sorting straight from catalog search using [advanced query](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/indexing-and-searching/searching-with-advancedquery) see also [its official docs](http://www.dieter.handshake.de/pyprojects/zope/AdvancedQuery.html#bct_sec_4)